# How do I handle null DateTime values included in a SQL SELECT * query?

Tags: c#, sql

After a SQL Select * query which results in one row, I set

```
        foundrows = Variables.PeopleTable.Select(SelectString);
        ThisRow = foundrows[0];
```

I set one DateTimePicker to a field StartDate:

```
        dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(ThisRow["StartDate"].ToString());
```

But a watch I have set on ThisRow["EndDate"] tells me that the name EndDate does not exist in the current context.  The SQL table shows it is NULL.
There are a lot of items on SO about how to handle this when the query result gives one value, rather than a complete row.
[Cast Null DateTime Value From Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339079/cast-null-datetime-value-from-database?rq=1) suggests it is simple, but if the value is not in this context that will stop any solution.
I've checked the spelling of the field.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It'll be `if (ThisRow["EndDate"] != DBNull) {`

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson `DBNull.Value` ;)

Comment: That gives 'DBNull' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: The line "if (ThisRow["EndDate"] != DBNull.Value"
threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: @OrmondStock can you follow this exact example and step through your code. If you don't know how to debug watch a 5 min YouTube video https://stackoverflow.com/a/12508016/495455 - you're getting that NullReferenceException because `ThisRow` must be null why only debugging can tell you.

Comment: Thank you.  Saved project, exited, rebooted, opened project, it works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also you should use `(DateTime)` cast rather than `Convert` with `ToString` which is really inefficient